# XSLT transformation for lazy fractions like ¾, ¼, ½, etc to be converted to 3/4, 1/4, 1/2

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, transformation

I have been trying to convert accented characters to normal alphabets utilizing normalize Unicode functionality. I was able to achieve to convert the accented characters. I have a new requirement to convert ¾ (lazy fraction) to 3/4 (normal fraction).

Here is the xslt I am using.

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-unicode(upper-case(translate(wd:Last_Name, ',', ' ')), 'NFKD'), '[^(\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}]','')"/>
```

Employee Last Name: Bistr¾anséky

Output I am Getting: BISTR34ANSEKY

When I am trying to pass some extra arguments in translate function, I am getting an error like 'you cannot pass 3 or more arguments in translate function'. How this one can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `normalize-unicode(., 'NFKD')` already gives you ASCII digits, only the fraction bar is not a slash but rather `&#8260;`, based on that you could use `replace(normalize-unicode(., 'NFKD'), '&#8260;', '/')`.